# One team project, multiple teams

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum

Is it possible to have one team project collection defined in TFS 2012 with multiple teams that work on different projects and each with its own product backlog, burndown chart, different access rights per branches/folders? If possible, can someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! though you can always begin with the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh528603.aspx), there have been a number of excellent posts on this subject, each discussing slightly different approaches on using teams:

- Colin Bird: [Multiple Teams with Microsoft Team Foundation Server
  2012 & Visual Studio Scrum V2.x](http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/colinbird/2012/11/19/MultipleTeamsWithMicrosoftTeamFoundationServer2012VisualStudioScrumV2xUpdated1452013.aspx)
- Martin Hinshelwood: [Teams without areas using a team field in Team
  Foundation Server 2012](http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2012-teams-without-areas/)
- René van Osnabrugge: [TFS as perfect tool for Scrum (Part 2) –
  Product Backlog Grooming](http://roadtoalm.com/2013/04/07/tfs-as-perfect-tool-for-scrum-part-2-product-backlog-grooming/)

Comment: Thanks, very usefull links, I also found the first link, my aproach was to create a "root" team and an area for it, after that I added the teams I needed and for each team I created an area. After this, I defined the iterations, so that the root team contained the product backlogs for each team and for each product backlog I created the sprints.